# How do I get a random word from the wordnet C library?

Tags: c, wordnet

Wordnet's documentation assumes I know the word I want to look for - "animal", in the example below - but I would like to get *any* word by searching through a specific part of speech (i.e. noun, verb, adverb, etc). How can I search for a random word like that?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <wn.h>

int main()
{
  // define variables
  char searchstr[] = "animal";
  struct ss *result;

  //initialize
  wninit();

  // find a word and get it as a datastructure
  // SynsetPtr *findtheinfo_ds(char *searchstr, int pos, int ptr_type, int sense_num);

  result = findtheinfo_ds(searchstr, 1, 2, ALLSENSES);

  printf("This sysnet's POS is: \n \n %s \n'", result -> defn);

  return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get a random word from the wordnet C library?

The data base format is documented in `man wndb`:

> Each index file is an alphabetized list of all the words found in WordNet in the corresponding part of speech. …

So, we can seek to a random position in the index file and take a word therefrom.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *pickword(char *file)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(file, "r");
    if (!fp) perror(file), exit(1);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    long end = ftell(fp);
    if (RAND_MAX < end) puts("RAND_MAX too small"), exit(1);
    int c;
    do
        fseek(fp, rand()%end, SEEK_SET),
        fscanf(fp, "%*[^\n]%*c"),           // skip partial line
        c = getc(fp);
     while (c <= ' ');                      // header lines start with space
    ungetc(c, fp);
    static char word[72];
    fscanf(fp, "%71s", word);
    fclose(fp);
    return word;
}

int main()
{
    puts(pickword("/usr/share/wordnet/index.noun"));
    puts(pickword("/usr/share/wordnet/index.verb"));
    puts(pickword("/usr/share/wordnet/index.adv"));
    puts(pickword("/usr/share/wordnet/index.adj"));
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That works well, but the randomness doesn't seem to work well. As it is now I get the same random word every time. . Am I right in thinking that it is the second argument of `fseek()` on line 13 that gives it the randomness?

Comment: You're right. To get other random numbers, you have to use `srand` once, e. g. `srand(time(NULL))`.

Comment: Brilliant, works now.